# XCTest to text for UILabel text existance

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I have a simple interface with 3 labels. I want to be able to determine the actual text that is assigned to a particular label. The text that is set inside of IB is "I have label text". The IB identifier for this label is "lastLabel".

```
    func testDetermineLabelText(){
         let app = XCUIApplication()
         let allLabels = app.staticTexts
         let labelPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "identifier contains[cd] 'lastLabel'") //i set the identifier in IB to be 'lastLabel'
         let foundLabel = allLabels.containing(labelPredicate)
         XCTAssert(foundLabel["lastLabel"].title == "I have label text")
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `UILabel`s, the text is available from the `label` property.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
let lastLabel = app.staticTexts["lastLabel"]
XCTAssertEqual(lastLabel.label, "Desired text")
```

Comment: Thank you for your coded example! It really helped me move forward with lots of other test. Have a great week!